# Can I find a file by filename only (i.e. extension unknown)

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

We have a network folder that is the landing place for csv files processed by different servers.  We alter the extension of the csv files to match the server that processed the file; for instance a file with the name `FooBar` that was process by Server1 would land in the network share with the name `FooBar.Server_1`.

The information I have available to to me is file name: `FooBar` and the path to the share.  I am not guaranteed the extension as there are multiple servers sending csv files to the network share.  I am guaranteed that there will only be one `FooBar` file in the share.

Is there a method in .net 2.0 that can be used to get the extension of the csv armed only with the path and filename?  Or do I need to craft my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles(NETWORK_FOLDER_PATH, "FooBar.*")[0]` will give you the full path.

`Path.GetExtension` will give you the extension.

If you want to put it all together:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(
    Directory.GetFiles(NETWORK_FOLDER_PATH, "FooBar.*")[0]);
```

Comment: I assumed he only cared about the extension in that he didn't know what it was. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
string[] results = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\\\sharepath\\here", "FooBar.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

if(results.Length > 0) {
    //found it
    DoSomethingWith(results[0]);
} else {
    // :(
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(yourPath)
{
  FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(FooBar.*);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the directory where the file will reside you can use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("SearchPattern")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx): `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("FooBar.*")`